# How are my popups not showing in my Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, r, popup, leaflet, raster

How can I make popups show up in leaflet that I plot using this code?

```
leaflet(df) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(-119.09, 43.70, zoom = 5) %>%
  addCircles(~long, ~lat, popup=df$hrus, color="#ffa500") %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", colors= "#ffa500", labels="HRUs", title="P")
```

I can see the dots, but nothing shows up on the popup (Inside RStudio view pane). I tried saving it as HTML, but the saved page neither has the basemap nor the popup

How can I do it?

dput(df)

```
structure(list(lat = structure(c(41.26124, 41.45247, 41.50923, 
41.57602, 41.62999, 41.60664, 41.63508, 41.83411, 41.84721, 41.84382, 
41.83294, 41.85096, 41.60179, 41.8572, 41.64224, 41.85058, 41.14342, 
41.77109, 41.35783, 41.39253, 41.78496, 41.5982, 41.66492, 41.70302, 
41.56481, 41.55544, 41.59929, 41.71257, 41.85876, 41.42739, 41.39722, 
41.76483, 41.49387, 41.46879, 41.50355, 41.95393, 41.8932, 41.96956, 
41.76675, 41.93061, 41.93767, 41.53439, 41.51667, 41.50472, 41.5053, 
41.67506, 41.68689, 41.78533, 41.79546, 41.87722), .Dim = 50L), 
    long = structure(c(-116.21489, -114.91972, -114.74541, -114.72553, 
    -114.83965, -114.81267, -114.84702, -113.49586, -113.48851, 
    -113.46151, -113.45017, -113.38449, -114.91356, -113.41496, 
    -114.85369, -113.50472, -116.21671, -114.25468, -116.32436, 
    -116.18391, -114.23875, -115.05154, -114.95098, -114.99438, 
    -115.75044, -115.89944, -115.84581, -114.9099, -114.19781, 
    -116.59131, -116.53819, -114.07782, -116.38066, -116.4347, 
    -116.33524, -113.51231, -113.51787, -113.55034, -114.96587, 
    -113.34303, -113.24616, -116.28699, -116.60549, -116.63497, 
    -116.55531, -115.19046, -114.72527, -114.64668, -114.54489, 
    -113.59969), .Dim = 50L), hrus = structure(1:50, .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
    "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", 
    "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", 
    "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("lat", 
"long", "hrus"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is this still an issue? I just ran your code and the map appeared along with the popup.

Comment: @Jul unfortunately it doesn't for me for some reason. I am using RStudio preview version. Also, it doesn't show up in rpubs when I publish.

Comment: Please post your session info/package versions. Maybe some clues there.